# Upload attachment for each step in ALM via vbscript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, automated-tests, alm

I'm struggling to identify the code, to upload attachment in HP ALM for each step. i.e, I want a screenshot/file to be attached for each step inside a test.

Note: I can able to attach file a RUN level.

Someone please pitch into this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the Run object then you can try the following:

```
Set stepFactory =  yourRunObject.StepFactory
Set stepList = stepFactory.NewList("")
Set firstStep = stepList.Item(1)

Dim attachFactory As AttachmentFactory
Set attachFactory = firstStep.Attachments
Set attachment = attachFactory.AddItem (Null)
attachment.FileName = "absolute_path_of_file"
attachment.Type = TDATT_FILE
attachment.Post
```

The code is an example to attach a file for the firt step of the run, but all you need to do is repeat the code for each step you want to attach.